# Add finish publishing function to a div joomla

Tags: php, date, joomla

How dio i make a div in joomla 3.0 stop pulishing after a specifik date ? 
My code shows how i want to make my function to work.

```
<?php
if (div class isset (MyDiv)) {
stop publish after 2013-12-12
}
?>
<html>
<div class="MyDiv">
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built into Joomla.

1. Open your article in the Content Manager
2. Click on the tab called "**Publishing**"
3. Select a date from the "**Finish Publishing**" option.

Hope this helps

Comment: I dont need he function top stop pulishing atricles i need to stop publishing a <div> inside the article.